# Should I use ActiveSupport::Notifications to implement activity feed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, activity-streams

I'm thinking about my options here.

- implement it with after_create/after_update hooks in activerecord with models.
- using ActiveSupport::Notifications to decouple activity feed objects with models.
- use observer.

I wasn't able to find much information about the second approach. And I imagine the third one is kinda like the first one. Am I using ActiveSupport::Notifications wrong? Why?

Comment: Are you needing to broadcast the activity feed to multiple users?

Comment: @wurde No. It's a communal feed, all user's activities will be shared.

Comment: Ok. I'm not that familiar with ActiveSupport::Notifications either, perhaps you could store your activities in ActiveRecord and a cache of recent activities client-side.

Comment: @wurde, thanks for looking into it anyways. I'm guessing not many people is taking the second route for some reason. Even with fan-out-on-write feeds, ActiveSupport::Notification support a queue natively, which makes it even more interesting option and makes me more curious.

Comment: @randomor I have always felt more confident with decoupled systems. The article you mentioned in the answer just presents some use cases, every one has different needs and goals. I think you should go with the second route, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this post about using ActiveSupport::Notification to implement email notifications. It might be similar with activity streams.

http://alma-connect.github.io/techblog/2014/03/rails-pub-sub.html

Comment: Nice read. Thanks for the URL. I like that it includes some use cases for ActiveSupport::Notifications coupled with background jobs.